# How to disable first option in an Ember.js select menu

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm pretty new to Ember, and I'm loving it so far! However, I feel like I've lost a little bit control over some of my HTML elements, in particular the `<select>` menu and it's `<option>`s.

I'd like for the default (`selected`) `<option>` to be disabled as well, i.e. have the attribute `disabled`. I'm used to this approach for setting a "placeholder" on select menus, but I'm up for other suggestions as well.

For example, if I had a select menu for gender, I'd want to end up with this piece of code:

```html
<select>
  <option selected disabled>Please select gender</select>
  <option value="m">Male</select>
  <option value="f">Female</select>
</select>
```

I have the following JavaScript and Handlebars code:

#### JavaScript

```js
genders = [
  Ember.Object.create({value: 'm', label: 'Male'}),
  Ember.Object.create({value: 'f', label: 'Female'}),
];

App.GenderSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
  contentBinding: "genders",
  optionValuePath: "content.value",
  optionLabelPath: "content.label"
});
```

#### Handlebars

```
{{view App.GenderSelect prompt="Please select gender"}}
```

#### Generated HTML

This gives me almost the code that I want. However, the first `<option>` is missing the `disabled` attribute, hence this question.

```html
<select>
  <option value>Please select gender</select>
  <option value="m">Male</select>
  <option value="f">Female</select>
</select>
```

Also, it doesn't set the `selected` attribute, but that's not strictly necessary, because it is the first option in the menu.

I appreciate any answers, both direct answers to this question and valid suggestions for using some other approach than `disabled`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That HTML is hard-coded into the template and there's no brain-dead simple way to do it.

That said, you can subclass Ember.Select with the following

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    this.$('option:first').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

You could also use the `layout` property to insert the placeholder manually above the auto-rendered options:

```
layout: precompileTemplate("<option selected disabled>Please select gender</option>{{yield}}")
```

Seeing as that would also require a subclass, I think it wiser to use `didInsertElement`.

Comment: The first approach is exactly the way to do it, thanks a bunch! It's so obvious after you mention it, though, can't believe I sat for an hour trying to figure this one out. :-)

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but Ember.Select has a dedicated way to do this called 'prompt'. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#toc_supplying-a-prompt

Comment: @Caqu: `prompt` does not disable the first element, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shamelessly leverages @ChristopherSwasey's answer, but will affect all `Ember.Select`s globally that use the `prompt` attribute.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'ember-select-with-nullprompt',

    initialize: function(container, application) {
        Ember.Select.reopen({
            didInsertElement: function () {
                if (this.prompt)
                    this.$('option:first').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```